# Python regex for module-level constants

Tags: python, regex, full-text-search

I have looked back and forward for a possible solution to my issue, but I guess my google-fu is very poor today. Not to mention my knowledge of regular expressions, which is close to zero.

I am trying to retrieve the definition of some "constants" (i.e., module-level global variables) from a series of Python files using text processing only. Basically, I read the whole text of a Python file and then I apply a regex to the text to find out where/what these "constants" are.

As an example, I can have in my Python file something like this:

```
CONSTANT_ONE   = 0    # standard
CONSTANT_RIGHT = 1    # rotation of 90 on the right
CONSTANT_LEFT  = 2    # rotation of 90 on the left
```

And I found out that this regex works OK to extract the variable *names*:

```
re.compile('^(\w+)[ \t]*=', re.M)
```

However, it badly fails with declarations like these:

```
NAME1, NAME2 = 0, None
CONST_1, CONST_2, CONST_3 = range(3)
```

Is there any way in which I can modify my regex to handle both cases? My apologies if this is a very basic question but I am really no expert of regex...

Thank you in advance.

Andrea.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an easy way to achieve this using regular expressions. It's possible to `compile` the Python modules and walk down the `AST` to find variable definitions. See the documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#compile and http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#module-ast.

**EDIT:** My current program, using the idea from @Sven.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ast
import sys

# example assignment.
a, b=5, 9

class MyNodeVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
        """
        Visit nodes in AST. Idea from @Sven.
        """
        def visit_Name(self, node):
                if isinstance(node.ctx, ast.Store):
                        print "Assigning name '%s' on line %d" % ( \
                                node.id, node.lineno)
        def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
                pass
        def visit_ClassDef(self, node):
                pass

def printAssignments(name):
        """
        Read Python file and print a list of variable assignments.
        """
        # read file.
        f=open(name, 'rU')
        data=f.readlines()
        f.close()

        # create AST.
        t=ast.parse("".join(data), filename=name, mode='exec')

        # find assignments.
        MyNodeVisitor().visit(t)

        # walk nodes.
        # for node in ast.walk(t):
        #       if isinstance(node, ast.Name) \
        #          and isinstance(node.ctx, ast.Store) \
        #          and node.col_offset == 0:
        #               print "Assigning name '%s' on line %d" % (node.id, node.lineno)

# print all assignments from files.
for name in sys.argv[1:]:
        print "=== %s ===" % name
        printAssignments(name)
        print "====%s====" % ('='*len(name), )
```

Comment: I didn't say he can't, I said it's not easy, and using ast is easier than using a regular expression. I added some example code, from there he got to walk along the nodes by himself.

Comment: Your new code won't find `b` in `a, b = 2, 3`.  What you are trying is hard to achieve using `ast.walk()` because it doesn't provide any context.  Moreover, I don't even think it is desirable -- for example if there is an assignment inside a try/except block in module scope (which is quite common), why exclude the assigments occurring there?

Comment: I've incorporated your idea in my code by not descending into class or function definitions.

Comment: Hmmm... good point.I tried both a visitor and walk, but both have the same drawback. Guess the `col_offset == 0` does not work like this. Suggestions?

Comment: No, the `NodeVisitor` doesn't have the same drawback.  I already implemented the basic idea in my code.

Comment: Updated example with my current AST program, including your visitor.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regular expressions, use Python's parser instead.  It is much simpler:

```
class TargetExtractor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.ctx, ast.Store):
            print node.id
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        pass
    def visit_ClassDef(self, node):
        pass

TargetExtractor().visit(ast.parse("a, b = 2, 3; c = d"))
```

prints

```
a
b
c
```

Instead of the string, you can also pass the whole contents of a file to `ast.parse()`.

Comment: Ok, I now like your code better ;-) Additionally, it prints assignments in blocks like `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

Comment: @hochl: The fact that my original code also included assigments inside functions was certainly a valid objection. :)

Comment: We've totally exploded the answer now, and the OP seems to not come back to his question ^^

Comment: Thank you guys for your answer. I guess there is no way then to use a regex to do what I need, as the results obtained using the proposed solution '^([\w\s,]+)=' need more work to get the variable names nicely in a list. I'll see if the ast approach is as fast as the regex one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for what purpose you are doing this, but if it has to be a regex for some reasons (if not Svens answer seem quite nice +1), this here would be one:

```
^([\w\s,]+)=
```

See it here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v1q0)

But this is much more general and match more than you wants.